# Getting data from different services

Tags: clojure

I have a piece of code that tries to get some data from a different services, falling back to the next one if previous fails.

The code look a little bit ugly, though. Any suggestions on how to rewrite it in a more concise way?

```lisp
(defn get-data [query]
  (let [data-cached (get-data-from-cache query)
        data-service-1 (if (nil? data-cached)
                         (get-data-service-1 query)
                         data-cached)
        data-service-2 (if (nil? data-service-1)
                         (get-data-service-2 query)
                         data-service-1)
        data (if (nil? data-service-2)
                   (get-data-service-3 query)
                   data-service-2)]
    data))
```

Comment: The title of your post should be the function/purpose of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `or` macro could be used here:

```
(defn get-data [query]
   (or (get-data-from-cache query) 
       (get-data-service-1 query) 
       (get-data-service-2 query) 
       (get-data-service-3 query)))
```

`or` short-circuits, so the first match will return and the rest will not be evaluated